# Maximum number of Django sessions

Tags: django, session

I work on an application that uses file-backed sessions (I know, I know).  Right now it is especially susceptible to DoS attacks b/c it allocates a session for every request, authenticated or not.

**Is there an easy (i.e. default) way to set a maximum number of sessions, and purge old sessions if that limit is reached?**  I could just write another middleware layer that checks the number of files in the session directory and purges old ones if it's above a threshold, but is there an easier way?

**And I understand**, file-backed sessions are worthless.  But I'm not the one that designed the system, I've just got to deal with it, so please don't just send me to some website about Django or mod_limitipconn.

Comment: I would consider writing a script to run on the crontab, rather than a middleware, which would add an overhead to every request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/sessions/#clearing-the-session-table):

> session data can accumulate...and Django does not provide automatic purging

I guess I'll just have to make it work properly.  Crap.